# Split array in C#

Tags: c#, string

How to split an array of string type equally into several array.
eg.
string[] input={"a","b","c","","d","e","f"}
 dynamically set{ string[] output="a","b","c",""//first time 
string[] output="d","e","f",""//second timetime }

Comment: What did you try? What _exactly_ are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Magic 8-ball says "Length" and "Substring", but it might as well say "It could happen"...

Comment: I think the OP is asking for an algorithm he can apply to any case when you have strings which can be split into a number of different configurations (component parts of varying lengths). I think it's a deeper question than you assume.

Comment: @hugh then maybe edit his post to make this clear? It'l just get voted down otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] splitString(int len, string input)
{
  int idx = 0;
  List<string> ret = new List<string>();
  while(idx < input.Length)
  {
    if (idx+len > input.Length)
      ret.Add(input.Substring(idx));
    else
      ret.Add(input.Substring(idx,len));
    idx+=len;
  }
  return ret.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You didn't read the question carefully. Given as inputs a string an a number, you need to get substrings that are the length of the number.

Comment: @Oded yes you're right.. I've adopted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I implemented the `Enumerable#each_slice` from Ruby in C# and it seems you could use that to get what you want.

```
static class ExtentionsMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, int size)
    {
        while (seq.Any())
        {
            yield return seq.Take(size);
            seq = seq.Skip(size);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just

```
var str = "1234567890";
var res = str.Split(5);
```

but since the result is an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<char>` you might want to also

```
var arr = res.Select(c => String.Join("", c)).ToArray();
```

to get a

> arr {string[2]}
>       [0]: "12345"
>       [1]: "67890"